# Windows RPC RpcEpResolveBinding failure

Tags: c++, windows, rpc

```
 RpcEpResolveBinding call fails with 1753 error. 
 1753. There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
```

RpcStringBindingCompose

RpcBindingFromStringBinding
calls go through fine and the subsequent call to RpcEpResolveBinding fails.
Asking for suggestions on what all things I can check.

Comment: *If no compatible server instances are registered in the endpoint-map database, the resolve-binding operation returns the `EPT_S_NOT_REGISTERED` status code.*

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! , how can I check the endpoint-map database? also which API is used to register the server instance so that I can check if the server is missing something setup code.

Comment: but who is write server ? are you call `RpcServerRegisterIf3, RpcServerUseProtseqEpW, RpcServerListen` ?

Comment: Thanks. I am working on an application which needs to the service. The service already exists and running. I am not sure if the service used the above APIs to register, but I will check and get back on that.

Comment: but you know name of endpoint ? you want call some api on interface - so you must know it signature, etc. but you dont know are server register/start listen ?

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that the protocol sequence and authentication service was incorrect. After fixing that, I don't see any issues in the RPC setup APIs but now when I call the actual remote procedure, I don't see call going through. How can I check where and what is failing? How can I check the RPC runtime logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219649/discussion-between-anup-buchke-and-rbmm).

Comment: @RbMm , I pasted my question details in the chat window. I would appreciate if you could let me know your inputs on that.